# Use function argument as name for new data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, assign, function-parameter

this is very simple, but I have searched and failed to find a solution for this small problem.

I want to use the argument of a function as the name for a new data frame, for example:

```
assign.dataset<-function(dataname){
    x<-c(1,2,3)
    y<-c(3,4,5)
    dataname<<-rbind(x,y)
}
```

Then

```
assign.dataset(new.dataframe.name)
```

just creates a new dataset with the name *dataname*.

I have tried to use the *paste* and *assign* functions but with no success.

Many thanks

Comment: This not a good way to do things in R. While technically possible, functions should not create variables outside of their own scope. Consider something more like `dataname <- create_dataset()` where `create_dataset()` just returns `rbind(x,y)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
assign.dataset<-function(dataname){
  x<-c(1,2,3)
  y<-c(3,4,5)
  assign(deparse(substitute(dataname)), rbind(x,y), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

assign.dataset(new.dataframe.name)

new.dataframe.name
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
x    1    2    3
y    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `rlang` equivalent to @Andrew's answer:

```
library(rlang)

assign.dataset<-function(dataname){
  x<-c(1,2,3)
  y<-c(3,4,5)
  assign(quo_name(enquo(dataname)), rbind(x,y), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

assign.dataset(test_df)
```

`enquo` captures the argument provided by the user and bundles it with the environment which the function was called into a `quosure`. `quo_name` then converts the `quosure` into a character.

However, I would advice **against** doing this instead of assigning the output of your function to an object. The following is how I would do it:

```
assign.dataset<-function(){
  x<-c(1,2,3)
  y<-c(3,4,5)
  rbind(x,y)
}

test_df = assign.dataset()
```

**Result:**

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
x    1    2    3
y    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

The above responses still require you to manually give the data.frame a name, just use a function to assign it. This makes little sense...

In my case I had a bunch of csv files to load into data.frames named like the file names. I used simple `assign` in a loop for this (`files` vector holds the names of csv files without extension, and `path` is the folder):

```
for (i in files) {
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(path, "/", i, ".csv", sep="")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```