# use function argument as name of dataframe using super-assignment <<-

Tags: r, function, assign

I'm looking to assign a `data.frame` to the global environment so that the name of the `data.frame` is the same as the one passed into a function I create. The typical [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516904/use-function-argument-as-name-for-new-data-frame-in-r) to do this is using `assign(arg_name, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)`:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  
  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  print(arg_name)
  
  x[["newvariable"]] <- 1
  
  assign(arg_name, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)

}

my_fun(mtcars)
```

which works but I'm trying to do the short hand version using "[super-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785290/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-and-in-r)": `<<-`. I haven't been able to make it work as it just returns a `data.frame` called `arg_name` rather than `mtcars`:

```
my_fun2 <- function(x) {
  
  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) 
  print(arg_name)
  
  x[["newvariable"]] <- 1
  
  arg_name <<- x
}

my_fun2(mtcars)
```

Any suggestions? Also, is `deparse(substitute(x))` still the best (shortest) way to extract the name of the `data.frame` for this type of case?

Thanks

Comment: `<<-` does not necessarily assign to the global environment. If you want to do this, use `assign`. But, can you explain why you are doing this? R tries to be a functional language and you are breaking that paradigm (and doing that is not recommended). There are a few cases where that can be justified (usually for better performance) but I don't see that here.

Comment: thanks this seems to answer my question (just use `assign`)... The only reason was to shorten `assign(arg_name, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)` syntax using `<<-`. I often use `<<-` if I `source` a long script (where I create its own environment) that has many objects in it but I just want one object passed from that environment to the global one to be used in other analysis

Comment: Yes, very bad practice. You are creating code that is confusing to others and difficult to maintain. Learn to create and use functions with proper return values instead.

Comment: In R, it is usually recommended that the scoping operator, `<<-`, and `assign` are rarely used, if not used at all. See Dirk's final quoted warning in your linked SO post: *The Evil and Wrong use is to modify variables in the global environment.*

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments that it is a bad practice, but it's worth understanding why the second variant of function not working.

```r
my_fun2 <- function(x) {
  
  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x))  #line 1
  print(arg_name)                       
  
  x[["newvariable"]] <- 1
  
  arg_name <<- x                      #line 4
}
```

In line 1, you have created a variable `arg_name` that exists only in function's loval environment. Whereas in line 4, you have created another variable `arg_name`. If you were to use `<-` it would overwrite the `arg_name` value in line 1, but since you are using `<<-` operator, it behaves differently. `<<-` will cause a search for `arg_name` in parent environment (1 level above, not in function environment) and if in case the variable is not found in the search path, a new variable `arg_name` will be created in your Global Env.

Hence you see, the name of your dataframe as `arg_name` in your global env, rather than `mtcars`.

As per the best approach, the first function seems to be the one.

Alternate approach could be to use a combination of `eval` and `substitute`, but with caution.

```r
my_fun3 <- function(x){
    arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    x[['newvariable']] <- 1
    eval(substitute(arg_name <- x), env=.GlobalEnv)
}
```